# can rails form select not use database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a rails application where I need to define a form with dropdown selections.
I do not want to have any db transactions involved so I defined a method `foo` in my helper function. However, when a user selects an option from dropdown, how would my method process the value?

haml:

```
f.select :foo, [["12345", "label 1"], ["abcdef", "label 2"]]
```

helper:

```
def foo
  # how do I store the selected option from haml?
end
```

Comment: i think you could store the selected option in either cache or cookies.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with it...

Comment: I want to have `foo` store some property (say an id in `string` form) of the parent class. I can use cache in this scenario but I just don't know how to let the helper function take the selected option from the haml page

Comment: There is just way to much wrong with the premises of this question for it to be answerable. The Rails form helpers just deal with objects and don't actually care if its stored in the database or not. "I just don't know how to let the helper function take the selected option from the haml page" - if you mean here that you want to get option as the user is interacting with the page then thats not possible  since the helper is running on the server and the user is interacting with the page on the client.

Comment: Also helpers in a Rails app don't even deal with user input. They are just helper methods to deal with HTML generation in the view. Controllers take user input and pass it to models and the view.

Comment: sorry my question seems a bit dumb and I do not fully understand the MVC structure in Rails. I'm able to define an empty `foo` method in my model, and my controller is able to take user input via params[object][:foo]. Would this logic make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Using models that are not backed by a database is pretty easy in Rails:

```
class Thing
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :foo
  attribute :bar
  attribute :baz
end
```

```
<%= form_with(model: @thing, url: '/foo', method: :get) do |form| %>
  <%= form.select :foo, [["12345", "label 1"], ["abcdef", "label 2"]] %>
<% end %>
```

```
class ThingsController
  # GET /foo
  def foo
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
  end

  private

  def thing_params
    params.fetch(:thing)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
  end
end
```

`form.select :foo` will call `form.object.foo` to set the selected value. Where object is the model that you passed. This generally applies to any sort of input when your passing a model to the form builder.

So for example if you set a default:

```
class Thing
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :foo, default: "abcdef"
  # ...
end
```

This option will be preselected. You can also explicitly set the value when calling the helper:

```
<%= form_with(model: @thing || Thing.new, url: '/foo') do |form| %>
  <%= form.select :foo, [["12345", "label 1"], ["abcdef", "label 2"]], selected: "abcdef" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example! This definitely helps me understand it a lot clearer